# List of big-O analysis for Python datastructures

Tags: python, performance, data-structures

Is there a list of the different data structures and their big-O access times for Python?

I was rummaging through the standard library docs and didn't see any, hence the question. :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not in the manual, it's [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the python wiki.

The table also includes complexities for methods for the data structures as well. Thanks for asking, I'd never seen this before until I looked for it.